# How to stack limits for maths operators?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, stacking-symbols

I have a question on how is it possible to create a `\sum` with two lower limits directly positioned right underneath each other. I have tried hard and cant seem to get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I like it better when the `i` and `j` are aligned:

This is done by `\mathrlap` and `\mathclap` (see [this TuGboat article](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf)). The article describes the use of some new macro's, including:

```
\def\mathrlap{\mathpalette\mathrlapinternal} 
\def\mathclap{\mathpalette\mathclapinternal}
\def\mathllapinternal#1#2{\llap{$\mathsurround=0pt#1{#2}$}}
\def\mathrlapinternal#1#2{\rlap{$\mathsurround=0pt#1{#2}$}}
```

add these to your preamble (or load the [`mathtools`](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf) package) and you can do something like this:

```
\[
\sum\limits_{\substack{\mathllap{1\le} i \mathrlap{\le 10} \\ \mathllap{1 \le} j \mathrlap{\le 5}}}^\infty x^i y^j
\]
```

which produces, in my opinion, a far superior result:

[image: example]

Note that I've added the upper limit `\infty`as an example, although I don't see how `i` and `j` would be smaller than 10 of 5 and still run up to ininity (ah well, it's just an example).

Comment: maybe it should also be said that the `\mathclap` etc... macros (or some slightly improved version of them, according to the doc) are available via the `mathtools` package?

Comment: ok yes, I didn't know that myself (I only skimmed the article once), great tip!

Answer (score 29):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
  \sum_{\substack{1 \le i \le 10\\ 1 \le j \le 5}}^\infty x^{i} y^{j} \qquad
  \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{1 \le i \le 10\\ 1 \le j \le 5}}}^\infty x^{i} y^{j}
\]  

\end{document}
```

[image]

see also http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf

Comment: Thanks a ton. I never knew of this command. Could you please edit your answer to show how to also inlcude the top limit, say "infinity".

Comment: @night owl: it is done as usual, see edit

Comment: you didn't update the image, so perhaps mention that `\infty` will indeed appear.

Answer (score 14):

Use `\substack`, as in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{\substack{1 \le i \le 10\\ 1 \le j \le 5}} x^{i} y^{j}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces: [image]