# Force line break inside a \lim argument in align environment

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, amsmath, align

Inside an `align` environment I have a `\lim` with two variables which should be displayed in two lines:

```
\begin{align}
...
f & = \lim _ {a \rightarrow -\infty \linebreak b \rightarrow \infty} ... \\
...
\end{align}
```

Currently there is no line break where I want to have one; it's displayed in one line. How can I force a line break there? `\linebreak` is ignored and `\\` breaks the `align` environment.

Comment: levu: You may consider reading this for other alternatives to stacking limits, below: 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17066/how-to-stack-limits-for-maths-operators

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `substack` to specify the two variables.

As egreg pointed out you can also use `subarry` and the last two solutions provided use this. The last one also account for the fact that the `a` and `b` don't take up the same amount of space, and create a box the width of an `x` and centers the `a` and `b` within that amount of space.

[image]

Also, in this case it is better to use `\to` instead of `\rightarrow` as that better represents the mathematical sense here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\AlignChar}[1]{\makebox[1ex][c]{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle#1}}}%
\begin{align}
 \lim _{\substack{a \to -\infty \\ b \to \infty}} =
 \lim _{\begin{subarray}{l} a \to -\infty \\ b \to \infty \end{subarray}} =
 \lim _{\begin{subarray}{l} \AlignChar{a}  \to -\infty \\ \AlignChar{b} \to \infty \end{subarray}}
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

As per egreg's comments, you could also write:

```
\newcommand*{\AlignChar}[1]{\makebox[1ex][c]{$\scriptstyle#1$}}%
```

which would make that macro easier to read, but my personal preference is to use `\ensuremath` as that to me explicitly captures the fact that it can be used in mode.  In this case, the reason that `$...$` is ok is that `\makebox` enters text mode so you can use `$..$` or `\ensuremath` inside it.

Comment: Or, maybe better, `\lim _{\begin{subarray}{l} a \to -\infty \\ \hphantom{a}\to \infty \end{subarray}}`

Comment: @Peter: Are you missing a "b" before the second "\rightarrow"? (see also Werner's answer...)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks. Have corrected it, and also took that opportunity to enhance the solution.

Comment: Why `\ensuremath`? Wouldn't `$\scriptstyle#1$` be easier to read?

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for pointing that out. Have added it to the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a, perhaps less attractive, alternative to stacking limits to operators by using `\mathop`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f & = \mathop{\lim_{a\rightarrow-\infty}}_{b\rightarrow\infty}
\end{align}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: thank you, maybe i need this at other points, here i'll use the stacking ;)

Comment: @Werner: Are you missing a "b" before the second "\rightarrow"? (Same issue as in Peter's answer...)

Comment: @Mico: Is it that obvious that I copied the MWE from Peter? :)

Comment: @Werner - A separate matter: I really admire your habit, in your answers, of providing each package's source URL as a comment. Great help for beginning LaTeXers, for sure!

Comment: A hah, now we know where you get your solutions. :-) :-)