# Newline within underbrace in math environment

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, text-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I force a line break within \text{…}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/how-can-i-force-a-line-break-within-text)

In the MWE below, is it possible to force a line break in the text under the Z so that the overall equation is more compact in the horizontal direction? I tried a normal linebreak, which I hoped would work since it's inside a `\text`, but that gave me errors.

Also, if there's a better way to make this sort of equation callout, please let me know. `\underbrace` and `underset` and variants thereon are the only methods I'm familiar with at present.

The Cauchy-Schwartz equation below from the Navier-Stokes Wiki article shows the kind of line breaks I was hoping to get in the underbrace.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
        \underbrace{z}_{\text{Initial Acceleration}} = x + y
\]
\end{document}
```

**Underbrace linebreaks:**

[image: Equations with underbrace linebreaks]

Comment: Or this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30862/force-line-break-inside-a-lim-argument-in-align-environment/30864#30864

Comment: The question linked by Torbjorn T. does answers my question. However, I did not find it through any searches, which is why I asked it here. Thanks.

Comment: for future visitors, one can write a command similar to \text in a way shown by egreg's answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/text-inside-equation-with

Answer (score 1):

See chapter 7.5.4 on pp 129f. in http://tug.org/~hvoss for a better
vertical alignment.

Comment: Link is dead, name of the package or command?

Comment: Link is updated ...