# Text inside equation with \\

Tags: equations, text, underbrace, substack

Sometimes I want to plug in text using `overbrace`/`stackrel` inside an equation, and have it in more than one line. what is the most straightforward way to do it?

What I wish to have is in the picture below. My (somewhat dumb) workaround is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,times}
\begin{document}
$$e = \underbrace{m}_{\substack{\text{I wish this text}\\ \text{ to be in two lines}} }\cdot \underbrace{c^2}_{\text{and the same here} }$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any (better) solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do `\usepackage{mathptmx}` instead of `\usepackage{times}` or, even better, `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `\parbox` instructions. In the following example, I use `\Centering` (from the `raggede` package) rather than the basic `\centering` instruction, as `\Centering` provides automatic line length balancing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,newtxtext,ragged2e} % 'times' package is deprecated
\begin{document}
\[
E = \underbrace{m}_{\parbox{1.75cm}{\Centering\scriptsize I wish this text to be in two lines}}    
\cdot \underbrace{c^2}_{\parbox{1.25cm}{\Centering\scriptsize and the same here}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Other possibilities are mentioned below:

```
$$e = \underbrace{m}_{\substack{\text{I wish this text}\\ \text{ to be in two lines}}}\cdot \underbrace{c^2}_{\text{and the same here} }$$

$$e = \underbrace{m}_{\parbox{10em}{\scriptsize I wish this text  to be in two lines}}\cdot \underbrace{c^2}_{\text{and the same here} }$$

$$e = \underbrace{m}_{\text{I wish this text }\atop\text{to be in two lines}}\cdot \underbrace{c^2}_{\text{and the same here} }$$
```

Comment: Don't use `$$` to initiate and terminate display math mode in a LaTeX document. Use `\[` and `\]` instead. For more on this subject, see [Why is `\[ ... \] `preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) Aside: Your `\parbox{10em}` example does *not* place the text on two lines.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a `\textsubstack` command that applies `\text` to each chunk (separated by `\\`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\textsubstack}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_omer_textsubstack_input_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_omer_textsubstack_output_seq
    \l_omer_textsubstack_input_seq
    { \exp_not:n { \text {##1} } }
  \substack{ \seq_use:Nn \l_omer_textsubstack_output_seq { \\ } }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_omer_textsubstack_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_omer_textsubstack_output_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  e = \underbrace{m}_{\textsubstack{I wish this text\\to be in two lines}}
      \cdot \underbrace{c^2}_{\textsubstack{and the\\ same here}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

First the input is split at `\\`; then a new sequence is built surrounding each item with `\text{...}`, then the sequence is produced, with `\\` as separator.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here, I use `tabstackengine` to make the stacks.  While the stack could be made with a simple `\Longstack` from the `stackengine` package, the `\tabbedLongstack` (even without actual tabs) allows for the `\TABstackTextstyle` to be specified externally, which I am using here to specify the size of the undertext.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,times,tabstackengine}
\TABstackTextstyle{\scriptsize}
\setstackgap{L}{8pt}
\begin{document}
\[e = \underbrace{m}_{\tabbedLongstack{I wish this text\\  to be in two lines}}\cdot    
  \underbrace{c^2}_{\tabbedLongstack[l]{and the same\\here but with\\left alignment} }
\]
\[e = \underbrace{m}_{\tabbedLongstack[r]{I wish this text\\  to be right
  aligned\\ in three lines}}\cdot
  \TABstackTextstyle{\tiny}
  \setstackgap{L}{6pt}
  \underbrace{c^2}_{\tabbedLongstack[l]{and the same\\here but with\\left alignment\\
    and tiny} }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `\substack`/`\text` solution is quite reasonable, particularly as it does not require specifying the width.  Just be aware of spurious spaces.  However, if one wishes one can define a multiline version of `\text`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,times,varwidth}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textblock}[1]{%
{\mathchoice
  {\textblockdef@\displaystyle\f@size{#1}}%
  {\textblockdef@\textstyle\f@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  {\textblockdef@\textstyle\sf@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  {\textblockdef@\textstyle \ssf@size{\firstchoice@false #1}}%
  \check@mathfonts
  }%
}
\def\textblockdef@#1#2#3{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
  \everymath{#1}%
  \let\f@size#2\selectfont
  \baselineskip=\f@size pt
  \baselineskip=1.1\baselineskip
  \centering
  #3
  \end{varwidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  e = \underbrace{m}_{\textblock{I wish this text\\to be in two lines}}
      \cdot \underbrace{c^2}_{\textblock{and the\\ same here}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The definition of `\textblock` is based on that of `\text` from `amstxt.sty`, but just assumes we are in math mode.  It will adapt its font size according to its placement in the equation, and will inherit font characteristics of the surrounding text.  I have chosen to make the text centered in the box automatically.  The math sizing information contains no specification of the baselineskip, so I have chosen a value that is slightly tighter than normal text.