# \underset or \substack macro using \text{...} doesn't work with \\ to create multiple lines

Tags: multline, text-mode, substack

I have the following code:

```
$$\begin{aligned}
\cal A \models (\exists x \psi)_{\bar s/\bar x}[\alpha] & \usett{\iff}{def. of \\ substitution}  
\end{aligned}$$
```

where `\usett` (abbreviation of 'underset' with the last 't' standing for 'text')

```
\newcommand{\usett}[2]{\mathop{#1}\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{#2}}}}}
```

The above code does not work (in particular there is `\\` inside `\text`), but the following code does:

```
$$\begin{aligned}
\cal A \models (\exists x \psi)_{\bar s/\bar x}[\alpha] & \mathop{\iff}\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{def. of}\\ \text{substitution}}}}
\end{aligned}$$
```

**If I could get `\text{...}` to "distribute" over a string separated by `\\`, this would fix the issue. Is this possible? If not, is there another solution?**

---

P.S. is it possible to write `\underset` to have the same multiple line capabilities as `\substack`? I wrote this monstrosity:

```
% uset multiple lines, like substack, hence the plural 's' ending
\newcommand{\usets}[2]{\mathop{#1}\limits_{\mathclap{\substack{#2}}}}
```

which does seem to work, but of course I'd be very happy to see alternative solutions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, which is why I already answered it as community wiki

Comment: sorry that is auto-generated text from the "mark as duplicate" interacton.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347020/122640) in [Text inside equation with \\](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/text-inside-equation-with), which does exactly what I am looking for.

I don't want to delete my question since it may pop up in more search queries, so I decided to answer my question as CW.