# Multiline text under/over arrows

Tags: symbols, line-breaking, multline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I write multiple lines in a subscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/how-can-i-write-multiple-lines-in-a-subscript)
>   [Force line break inside a \lim argument in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30862/force-line-break-inside-a-lim-argument-in-align-environment)

I want to write some multi-line text under a long arrow. Normally I use `\xrightarrow[text below]{text over}`, but if I try to add a \\ in one of them (say, I want "text below" to have two lines), I get a compilation error.

What to do? I'm sure it's solvable.

Thanks,
John.

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stack Exchange! It would be helpful if you provided a full MWE (minimum working example) showing what you're trying to achieve. In the present case, information on the information you're trying to set below the `\xrightarrow` would be very useful, as would be details on the "compilation error" you report getting.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30862/force-line-break-inside-a-lim-argument-in-align-environment), and the links within.

Comment: cmhughes: Thanks! This syntax worked for me: '\xrightarrow[\begin{subarray}{l} a \\ b \end{subarray}]{}' (displaying a above b).
Mico: Thanks for the answer and the welcoming! As you can see I got it solved. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice there was a problem - how do I make both line appear in the centre of the line? I have a short and a long line, and they don't align...

Comment: @John: change `l` (left) to `c` (center) in the argument of `subarray`: `\begin{subarray}{c} a \\ b \end{subarray}`.