# Problem with the subscript of the summation sign written in the text

Tags: math-mode, formatting, subscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stack limits for maths operators?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17066/how-to-stack-limits-for-maths-operators)

The following is the text having summation sign

```
$\sum_{a,b}$ replacing $\sum_{a=1}^n\sum_{a=1,~b\neq a}^{n}$
```

that is within my text. Note that the subscript of

```
\sum_{a=1,~b\neq a}
```

is shown with a=1 and b!=a one after another, which might be distracting. How could I put them one on top of another? Another thing is the spacing between a and b in

```
$\sum_{a,b}$.
```

I'm trying to get them a bit larger spread between a and b, but $~b$ it is too large. Any solution to this? Documentclass:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
```

Comment: You can use a `substack` see Section 7.1 of `amsmath` documentation; I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: Duplicate: [How to stack limits for maths operators?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17066/5764)

Comment: to add some space in `{a,b}`. a thin space should do it: `{a,\,b}`.  regarding the use of `substack`, yes, that would put the limits on two lines, at the cost of fouled up baselines in that area of text.  but it's done ...; looks better in a display.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, with a thin space it looks much better.