# Centered equation with parenthetical information offset

Tags: equations

Is there an easy way to make the equation centered in this:

```
\[x_i = y_i \hspace{1.0em}(i=1,\dots,n)\]
```

The parenthetical information would be off to the right.

Comment: You might make the parenthetical information, together with the quad, zero wide; but why? The condition *is* part of the formula. By the way, `\hspace{1.0em}` is the same as `\quad`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with `mathtools`:

```
\[x_i = y_i \mathrlap{\quad(i=1,\dots,n)} \]
```

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17073/126840) gives the code for `\mathrlap` for those that are interested (I prefer to avoid using a whole package if all I need is one command, which I stick in my preamble instead).

Comment: Sure, but `mathtools`  is anyway a highly recommended package, which adds many useful features to `amsmath`.